# Convert VBA to VBS

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript, converters

I have a little VBA script with some functions that I would like to convert to a single VBS file.

Here is an example of what I got:

```vb
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Function ReadIniFileString(ByVal Sect As String, ByVal Keyname As String) As String
    Dim Worked As Long
    Dim RetStr As String * 128
    Dim StrSize As Long
    Dim iNoOfCharInIni As Integer
    Dim sIniString, sProfileString As String

    iNoOfCharInIni = 0
    sIniString = ""
    If Sect = "" Or Keyname = "" Then
        MsgBox "Erreur lors de la lecture des paramètres dans " & IniFileName, vbExclamation, "INI"
        Access.Application.Quit
    Else
        sProfileString = ""
        RetStr = Space(128)
        StrSize = Len(RetStr)
        Worked = GetPrivateProfileString(Sect, Keyname, "", RetStr, StrSize, IniFileName)
        If Worked Then
            iNoOfCharInIni = Worked
            sIniString = Left$(RetStr, Worked)
        End If
    End If
    ReadIniFileString = sIniString
End Function
```

And then, I need to use this function to put some values in strings. VBS doesn't seem to like any of my var declaration (`(Dim) MyVar As MyType`).

If I'm able to adapt that code to VBS, I should be able to do the rest of my functions too. How can I adapt/convert this to VBS? Thank you.

Comment: If you need `Access.Application.Quit`, probably your VBScript should automate an Access application instance.  And if you do that, the original VBA code may work unaltered within the Access instance.

Comment: @HansUp Obviously, I don't need `Access.Application.Quit` because there is no interface at all, I just end the script and the job is done. However, I'm still interested in your solution: running an Access instance unaltered. The purpose of this Access 2003 MDB project is to compact all the other databases. There is a little GUI with some buttons to choose which database to compact. It works pretty well. However, I now want to get all the job done automatically once a week, when everybody is out. That's why I have created a VBS script that Windows could run with the integrated Task Scheduler.

Comment: (the VBS script would compact ALL the databases without any GUI, obviously, and output the results into a log file)

Comment: `Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")`  That's the key object assignment for COM automation of MS Access.  You should be able to find scads of detailed examples with a little searching.

Comment: +1, thank you, it looks like a solid solution to my problem and I won't have to deal with VBS. But just for my information, do you think it's possible to convert the declaration of the `GetPrivateProfileString()` function from kernel32 lib into VBS?

Comment: I wondered about that point, too.  I've never attempted it in any of my VBScripts.  I did find this discussion: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?31534-VBScript-and-API&s=e714e8213fdad0379d00672c2df3d477&p=86696#post86696  I don't know whether that is the definitive answer, but it doesn't sound promising.  Please let us know if you can find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an MDB that does what you want, run the VBS script to open this mdb and set the AutoExec Macro to run the functions that compact these Databases and then self close the MDB.  This is a bit hacky but may prove to be the least troublesome.

Comment: It seems like a solid solution that I had not thought, I will search on how to use the `CreateObject("Access.Application")` provided by HansUp and try it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pitty i didn't see this earlier, anyway, for future reference here is a pure vbscript solution to read a value from an ini file. If anyone needs explanation on the used regular expression just leave a comment.

```
'this is the contents of test.ini'
' [Brussels]
' Address = "Postbox 3245_58348 Brussels"

' [Copenhagen]
' Address = "Postbox 2455_5478347 Copenhagen"

' [Paris]
' Address = "Postbox 8546_5412557 Paris"

section = "Brussels"
key = "Address"

const ForReading = 1
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.OpenTextFile("test.ini", ForReading)

'returns "Postbox 3245_58348 Brussels"'
wscript.echo get_key_of_ini(file.readall, section, key)

function get_key_of_ini(readFile, section, key)
  set regEx = New RegExp
  with regEx
    .Pattern = "(\[" & section & "\]\r\n)([^\[]+)"
    .IgnoreCase = True 
    .Global = True
  end With

  set matches  = regEx.execute(readFile)
  for x = 0 to matches.count-1
    set match = matches(x)
    For i = 1 To match.subMatches.count-1
      subMatches = match.SubMatches(i)
      if trim(split(match.SubMatches(i),"=")(0)) = key then
        get_key_of_ini = trim(split(match.SubMatches(i),"=")(1))
      end if
    Next
  next
end function
```

Comment: +1 for the turnaround but it (obviously) doesn't use the function of kernel32 library. But I understand that it will work fine. However, I just pasted that portion of the code to show what kind of problem I'm facing. If there is really no way to return a value from a VBS function, it means that I have to start from scratch to get the same job done that my VBA module. VBA and VBS, despite only being one letter different, look to be **A LOT** different now. Not the same language/syntax at all.

Comment: in this case not because of kernel32, that is difficult (but not impossible) to use in vbscript, but i could give you examples in which the difference is minimal. The main advantage of this script is that it can be used on its own without loading a database first and making a call to a library after. If you don't need the db for something else the speedup will be drastic

Comment: @peter Well, I need to read a INI file to get all the database paths, then I want to make a backup of every database and then compact each one. I guess I don't really need to run the MDB, no, but considering this routine will be run overnight, performance isn't a matter as much as saving time converting all this code each time I make a little edit.

Comment: if you start a vbs anyway, optimal is keeping all the logic there, you don't need the ini to keep the paths, a simple Array(path1, path2,..) will do, open them with vba code in your vbs, backup and compact them there, obviously you need logging also what is also best done in the vbs... just my opinion